# Graphviz drawing - make a box that starts at one node and goes to the end of another one

Tags: graphviz

I have a timeline and would like a box to be drawn next to a particular number of years

```
digraph timeline {

    node [fontsize=24, shape = plaintext];

    1940 -> 1950;
    1950 -> 1955;
    1955 -> 1960;
 
 
    node [fontsize=20, shape = box];
    { rank=same;  1940 test; }

}
```

This places a timeline on the left hand side going from 1940 to 1950 and so forth. I would like draw a box next to the numbers that starts at 1940 - which is what I do now with `{ rank=same;  1940 test; }` and that ends with 1955.

Here is an example of the box drawn at 1940

[image]

Here is an example of the box drawn at 1955 with code  `{ rank=same;  1955 test; }`

[image]

I would like to have the box drawn from the start of 1940 position to the end of 1955 position, so encompassing these two boxes right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky solution is to draw a cluster and place invisible nodes inside it using [`style=invis`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/style/). Then align the cluster with the timeline using [`newrank`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/newrank/).
Script:

```
digraph timeline {
    newrank=true;

    node [fontsize=24, shape = plaintext];

    1940 -> 1950 -> 1955 -> 1960;
    
    subgraph cluster_1 {
        test [fontsize=20]
        cl_start [shape=none style=invis]
        cl_end [shape=none style=invis]
        cl_start -> test -> cl_end [style=invis]
    }
    
    {rank=same;1940;cl_start}
    {rank=same;1955;cl_end}
}
```

Result:
[image: timeline made with GraphViz]

Answer (score 1):

No easy way to do this with Graphviz.

- **dot** does not allow nodes to span ranks.  It centers all nodes in the same rank on the same line (horizontal, with rankdir=TB).
- if you set rankdir=LR, you can get nodes to span years, but positioning &  node sizing become difficult
- you could put a node on every year you want the final node to span and the post-process the result to overwrite the several nodes with a single large node.
- you can us the **neato -n** (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords) capability and position & size all the nodes yourself
- or you could try another language entirely (maybe **pikchr** https://pikchr.org/home/doc/trunk/homepage.md)